# I need a String method in a Trigger to validate if a Rich Text Area is blank

Tags: apex, validation, string

I need assistance in evaluating whether a Rich Text Area custom field is blank using an Apex trigger.

Rich Text Field name: Application_Workaround__c

I have tried the following within the context of a trigger:

```
string.isBlank(new_application_dependency_record.Application_Workaround__c)
```

This method returns "true" if there is a single break within the rich text field "Application_Workaround__c". THe problem is that the 
 tag in the rich text field is not a valid value but the string method considers it to be a non-blank.

I also tried the following:

```
string.valueof(new_application_dependency_record.Application_Workaround__cApplication_Workaround__c).length() == 0;
```

I also tried:

```
string.new_application_dependency_record.Application_Workaround__cApplication_Workaround__c.length() == 0;
```

None of these methods seem to ignore blank space or the `<BR>` tag.

What is the best practice for determining if a rich text field is truly blank?

Comment: Have you tried `trim`? Something like `String.isBlank(new_application_dependency_record.Application_Workaround__c.trim())`?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. The underlying problem I am facing is the scenario where a user enters a line break or tries to delete all characters in the field yet a single or multiple "<BR>" HTML <BR> tag is still stored in Rich Text Field when you try to access that Rich Text Field in Apex using something like Object.FieldName. I don't believe that TRIM will remove the "<" or ">" characters as they are not "white space".

Comment: I think its a known issue with rich text boxes that they are never truly blank. Since you know that it contains the <br/> tag, can't you assume that its blank in this case?

Comment: https://sites.secure.force.com/appexchange/ideaView?id=08730000000i7CGAAY&tab=v

Answer (score 3):

You can remove all html tags (or just br if you want) and use isblank so that whitespace is not an issue.

```
String richtextstr = string.valueof(new_application_dependency_record.Application_Workaround__cApplication_Workaround__c);
richtextstr = richtextstr.replaceall('<.*>','');
string.isblank(richtextstr));
```